# Heroku (Python/Flask) web app truncating log messages to only one line

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have a simple Python/Flask web that contains this:

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    app.logger.warning('test message 1\ntest message 2\ntest message 3')
```

Note the newline characters.

When I run it with heroku local web I see this in the logs:

```
web.1  | WARNING:app:test message 1
```

But when I push it to heroku instead of running it locally I see:

```
2015-12-09T22:23:21.102478+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING in app[/app/app.py:17]: test message 1
2015-12-09T22:23:21.102482+00:00 app[web.1]: test message 2
2015-12-09T22:23:21.102483+00:00 app[web.1]: test message 3
```

Why does heroku local truncate the logs to the first line? I hate that and want it to stop.

My Procfile is:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file -
```

I know it is not Flask or gunicorn doing that because when I run gunicorn by itself, I see

```
WARNING in app [/home/vagrant/Projects/milestone1/app.py:20]: test message 1
test message 2
test message 3
```

It has to be heroku local.